# Eagerly initialize singleton actor in scalaguice

Tags: scala, akka, guice

I would like to eagerly initialize a singleton actor. I currently do the below and then later in my app startup get the instance of the actor.

```
`bind[Actor].annotatedWith(Names.named(LockCoordinator.name)).to[LockCoordinator].in[Singleton]`
```

I have tried
`bind[Actor].annotatedWith(Names.named(LockCoordinator.name)).to[LockCoordinator].asEagerSingleton()`

but  fails at runtime with

```
1) Error injecting constructor,   akka.actor.ActorInitializationException:   You cannot create an instance of [LockCoordinator] explicitly using the constructor (new). You have to use one of the 'actorOf' factory methods to create a new actor. See the documentation.
```

I do create an eagerSingleton already for the system, but couldn't figure out how to apply it for an Actor (not ActorRef)

```
class ActorSystemProvider @Inject() (val config: Config, val injector: Injector) extends Provider[ActorSystem] {
override def get() = {

  val system = ActorSystem(config.getString("mysystem"), config)
  GuiceAkkaExtension(system).initialize(injector)
  system
}
}
```

Is there a boilerplate free way of achieving this? As I want to apply this to 3-4 other actors

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

https://gist.github.com/fancellu/e4e8acdc3d7fd3b9d749352f9d6c68e3

```
import actors.ActorBrowserActor
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport

class Module extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport{
  def configure(): Unit = {
    bindActor[ActorBrowserActor](ActorBrowserActor.NAME, _=>ActorBrowserActor.props)
  }
}
```

here we inject the actor by name

```
class SampleController @Inject()(implicit system: ActorSystem, val messagesApi: MessagesApi, @Named("actor-browser-actor") actorBrowserActor: ActorRef)
  extends Controller  with I18nSupport{
}
```

Comment: Or you could try

https://gist.github.com/fancellu/7eb753b6ad12339bbb1171b0b8744228